# How specify clause Where in Mysql each 5 minutes

Tags: mysql

In a Mysql request, i would like to specify to select the values each 5 minutes

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime BETWEEN "2016-01-04 00:00:00" 
 $sql .= 'AND "2016-01-04 12:00:00" + "(and INTERVAL 5 minutes)"';
```

Does someone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2016-01-04 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-04 12:00:00'
GROUP BY 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) DIV 300
```